# How to disable new tab option in google chrome on a href using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I have an application which has multiple a href links. On right click they display "New Tab" in Chrome browser.
 On clicking that it opens a new tab ,but the application is not designed to work in a new tab. Is there any way to disable that option or catch the event of a new tab in Chrome. Thanks

Comment: do not have anchors, have spans with link css and handle onclicks.

Comment: if possible remove href from anchor tag and use onclick event.

Comment: If you're not going to use anchors, make sure to add `tabindex=0` so they are keyboard accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. It is a browser feature to open links in new tabs. That's, among others, the purpose of a link `<a>` tag.

However, you can use e.g. a `<span>` tag and attach an `onclick` handler on it to perform page navigation:

```
<span onclick="window.location.href='nextpage.html'">Next page</span>
```

Using CSS you can style the span to look like a link.

Answer (score 0):

The links open in new tab based on its target attribute, the target attribute specifies where to open the linked document.
Just remove `target="_blank"` from `<a>` tag or set `target="_self"`

Comment: You can still open links in a new tab using right click --> open in new tab in chrome.